# How to navigate into the SVG when forcing Flash SVG viewer on ie9

Tags: flash, svg, internet-explorer-9, embed, getelementbyid

I try to get an element in a svg that is embedded in an `<object>`. I use svgweb and force the flash viewer. I've created a little demo html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="svg.js"></script>
  <meta name="svg.render.forceflash" content="true">
 </head>
 <body>
   <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object data="simple.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
        width="500" height="500" id="testSVG"> <!--<![endif]-->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <object src="simple.svg" classid="image/svg+xml"
        width="500" height="500" id="testSVG"> <![endif]-->
   <!--[if gte IE 9]>
   <object data="simple.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
        width="500" height="500" id="testSVG"> <![endif]-->
</object>
```

The flash renderer replaces the `<object>` with `<div id="testSVG" style="visibility: hidden;" type="image/svg+xml" width="500" height="500" data="simple.svg">`.

The svg is very simple:

```
 <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <rect id="rect" x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100"
      style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
 </svg>
```

Now, I try to get the `<rect>`-element according to the manual ( http://svgweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/UserManual.html#manipulate_objects ):

```
var obj = document.getElementById('testSVG');
var doc = obj.contentDocument; // grab the document object inside your SVG file
var myRect = doc.getElementById('myRect');
```

ie9 tells me that the object doesn't support the property or method "getElementById".

I tried this on chrome too. Instead of the `<div>` above, the flash renderer makes a `<embed src="/svg.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="500" height="500" id="testSVG" name="testSVG" swliveconnect="true" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="uniqueId=testSVG&amp;sourceType=string&amp;clipMode=both&amp;debug=true&amp;svgId=testSVG" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" style="visibility: visible; " class="embedssvg">`.

`doc.getElementById('myRect')` does return an object.
In firefox, `obj.contentDocument` returns `undefined`.

I do not care about chrome and ff since they have sufficient native svg support. But I do need ie9 to get me elements in a svg - How do I do that; What am I doing wrong?